# How to extract power of ten results with grep command (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a program that gives me results in a scientific python format, like this :

```
10.0889E-002
```

for example.

I would like to use grep command (or awk) to extract this result but I don't find a way to treat correctly this "E-002". The corresponding result WITHOUT E-002 (but accounting for it) would be stored in a variable so that I can do all kind of operations with other variables and numbers.

I think I should obviously better use python, but I search for a quick and dirty solution for now.

Example :

Let's say I have a filename which just have one line containing :

```
10.0889E-002
```

or any number with this kind of notation.

I would like to get this into a variable in bash, but without power of ten notation. In myfile.sh :

```
a=`grep '' filename | awk '{print $1}'`
```

But this does not account for E-002 so that I can do all kind of operation with my variable a.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please show us some code that attempts to implement what you're after, then show us your expected results and the results you're actually getting?  An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always really helps improve a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` can interpret that just fine:

```
$ echo '10.0889E-002' | awk '{ print $1+0 }'
> 0.100889
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this +0 option of awk

Comment: You don't need that, it's just a way to force `awk` using a different representation of the number.

Comment: @B_runo I see your edited question now. In this case the `+0` is exactly what you need, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

use printf

```
$ printf "%f\n" 10.0889E-002
0.100889
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
-?\d*\.?\d+[eE]?-?\d*
```